# BEST Linux script; to rename SRT to name of movie file in same folder; multiple sub folders

Tags: linux, bash

There have been multiple attempts to answer this question, but no correct script can be found.

The problem:
SRT subtitles will not load unless having the same name as the movie, or same name as movie +.en.srt or .es.srt or .fr.srt and so on.

1000's of movie directories within a main movie directory having within their respective movie directory, sometimes 1+ .srt files (1_English.srt, 2_English.srt, *French.srt, etc.).

My media server is using Ubuntu, so the solution should use a BASH script.

Here is a snippet of my file structure:

```
Test-dir$ tree
.
├── renamer.sh
├── Saga.of.the.Phoenix.1990.1080p
│   ├── 1_French.srt
│   ├── 1_Spanish.srt
│   ├── 2_English.srt
│   ├── 3_English.srt
│   └── Saga.of.the.Phoenix.1990.1080p.BluRay.x265.mp4
├── Salt.and.Pepper.1968.1080p
│   ├── 1_French.srt
│   ├── 1_Spanish.srt
│   ├── 2_English.srt
│   ├── 4_English.srt
│   └── Salt.and.Pepper.1968.1080p.mp4
└── Salyut-7.2017.1080p.BluRay.x265
    ├── 2_English.srt
    └── Salyut-7.2017.1080p.BluRay.x265.mp4
```

The questions:
In writing a BASH script,

1. There are multiple srt files with the same language, I usually like to choose the bigger file and remove the smaller file, the first part of script would have to sort same language srt and delete the smaller ones, how to script this?
2. How to change the name of srt's to have the same name as the movie file (not always mp4, sometimes mkv or avi.), while appending acronyms for language (en, es, fr, ru,..) if English.srt then change name to "MovieName".en.srt?

I have started the script removing srt files from the SUB directories of the movie directory and then deleting the SUB directory.

Also, added a script to delete any unwanted parts in the string of the movie, or delete unwanted files.

```
#!/bin/bash/

# Using current working DIR of where script is ran from
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

# Moves srt files from SUB folders to their movie folder.
for i in */Subs; do
     mv "$i"/* "$i"/..
done

# Removes Subs directory.
find $DIR/* -type d -name "Subs" -exec rm -rf {} +

# Removing the additional rar string from the folders and their movie names.
find . -depth -name '*-rar*' -execdir bash -c 'for f; do mv -i "$f" "${f//-rar/}"; done' bash {} +

# Removing unwanted files from all movie folders.
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f \( -name "RAR.txt" -o -name "RAR.nfo" \) -delete

######## Your helper code starts from here to answer questions 1 and 2 #####################
```

Many thanks for helping with this conundrum, not only will this help one person, but many, on our quest to free many hours of copying, deleting, pasting, and all with a single script.

Update:
BTB91 gave a brilliant answer and has worked, however to help others learn the many ways to go about solving the same problem above I would like to keep this thread open.

Comment: Nothing against bash but just because you're running Ubuntu doesn't mean you're limited to it.  Have you tried python?  The os library has everything you need to do this and it will probably be much easier than with bash.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Michael but I'm not skilled in python, I know bash a little though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IFS=$'\n' eval "MOVS=(\$( find \"\$DIR\" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' ))" # list of movies
for M in "${MOVS[@]}" ; do
    cd "$DIR/$M"
    IFS=$'\n' eval "LANGS=(\$( ls | sed -nr 's/.*_([[:alpha:]]+).srt/\1/p' | sort -u ))" # list of languages for movie
    for L in "${LANGS[@]}" ; do
        IFS=$'\n' eval "FILES=(\$( ls -S *_$L.srt))" # list files for language sorted by size
        case "${L,,}" in
            en*)
                L=en
                ;;
            sp*|es*)
                L=es
                ;;
        esac
        mv -v "${FILES[0]}" "$M.$L.srt"
        FILES[0]=
        rm -vf "${FILES[@]}"
    done
    cd "$OLDPWD"
done
```

I used "IFS=$'\n' eval ..." because the directory  or file names might contain spaces.

Comment: Great work btb91, you've saved many long days with your help, many thanks!